# Shared WLAN between 2 houses ( Already tried some stuff )

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, wrt54gl

I've need some help guys and hope someone can help me out.

Well my Task is more or less common, but the HOW-TO's which i found on the net are mostly for greater distances or "i dont care about speed" solutions.

I want to share WLAN in two houses, ive already tryed some stuff but the connection slows down from time to time.

Avavible Hardware: (with DDWRT) 2 x Linksysy WRT54G 2 x TP-Link WR841ND 1 x Linksys WAG200G 1 x TP-Link SG108

Could someone help me out ?

PS: House B should get the fastest possible connection?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to install a cable from GB Hub to AP2? The 40 / 60 m of air distance are your weakest link.

Comment: Any wireless solution is going to be slow. Best way would be to install an Ethernet cable, if possible.

Comment: What kind of speeds are you looking for?

Comment: its not possible to connect part A (bridge1, Ap1) via cable with part B       Well the Part A got 16Mb, i whould be more than happy with a "normal" internet connection speed like 16Mb or somethink like that, theres no need for "LAN like GB" speed. From time to Time this kind of connection works smoothless but than it goes down and even ping packages are getting lost. And than it return to normal speed. i cant find a patern into this, i already checked to choose best WLAN channel depending on nearby WLAN channels

Comment: Well nobody around who can help me to fix this mess ?